# Issue with Django recognizing URL passed parameter

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I am learning Django and am having an issue with some simple testing and passing URL parameters.  Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('custnames', views.custnames, name='custnames'),
    path('custdetail/<int:cust_id>/', views.cust_detail, name='cust_detail'),
]
```

And here is my views.py

```
def cust_detail(request, cust_id):
    return HttpResponse('<p>Cust Detail View with cust_id {cust_id}</p>')
```

When I put this for my URL in my browser:  http://localhost:8000/custdetail/1/

My output is:

```
Cust Detail View with cust_id {cust_id}
```

The "home" and "custnames" sections seem to work fine.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?
~Ed

Comment: using `f` string if you want to pass variable str representation to string `f'<p>Cust... {cust_id}</p>'`

Comment: HttpResponse isn't a template, but a wrapper for an HTTP response, for which the first argument is its content. You're passing a string, so that string is put in there. Use an f string, string.format() or anything similar to replace the content with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "minglyu" and "Melvyn".  Adding the "f" worked.